# 2D Game Tile Placement Algorithm

Tags: java

[image: explanation]

Hey Guys,

Ok so I have been trying to figure this out for the past few days and I seriously have nothing left in me, Hence why I am here.

I am in the early stages of making a 2D game. I created an "Inventory" for developer mode which displays a grid of tiles (As seen at the bottom of the image).

You can place these tiles in the map grid, where they will then be saved as a char to a text file for future map loading.

Everything works as it should. However, I would like it so that when i place a path tile (Red Border) on the map when surrounded by other path tiles (Blue Border) it changes to the correct sided tile.

Here is my Tilemap.java.

```
 public class TileMap {

private Tile[][] tiles;

public TileMap(int width, int height) {
    tiles = new Tile[width][height];
}

public int getWidth() {
    return tiles.length;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return tiles[0].length;
}

public Tile getTile(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= getWidth() || y < 0 || y >= getHeight()) {
        return new VoidTile();
    } else {
        return tiles[x][y];
    }
}

public void setTile(int x, int y, Tile tile) {
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
        tiles[x][y] = tile;
    }
}

}
```

ok so in my Main game class I have a TileMap map;

I am trying to update the tiles as I place them down in the mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) method by checking the up, down, left and right tiles of the soon to be placed tile like so.

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Inventory.click(e);

    if (e.getButton() == 1) {
        tempTile = Inventory.getSelectedTile();
        System.out.println("Selected Tile is " + tempTile);
    } else if (e.getButton() == 3) {
        
        boolean u = map.getTile(mouseGridX, mouseGridY - 1).connectsToPath;
        boolean d = map.getTile(mouseGridX, mouseGridY + 1).connectsToPath;
        boolean l = map.getTile(mouseGridX - 1, mouseGridY).connectsToPath;
        boolean r = map.getTile(mouseGridX + 1, mouseGridY).connectsToPath;
        boolean ul = map.getTile(mouseGridX - 1, mouseGridY - 1).connectsToPath;
        boolean ur = map.getTile(mouseGridX + 1, mouseGridY - 1).connectsToPath;   
        boolean dl = map.getTile(mouseGridX - 1, mouseGridY + 1).connectsToPath; 
        boolean dr = map.getTile(mouseGridX + 1, mouseGridY + 1).connectsToPath;   
             
                    if (!u && !l && !d && !r) {
                       map.setTile(mouseGridX, mouseGridY new PathTile(5));
                    }
            }
  }
```

here is my PathTile.java constructor which uses a grid based sprite sheet. getSprite(GridX,GridY)

```
    public PathTile(int tile) {
    this.tile = tile;
    connectsToPath = true;
    
    switch (tile) {
    case 1:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(1, 1);
        break;
    case 2:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(2, 1);
        break;
    case 3:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(3, 1);
        break;
    case 4:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(1, 2);
        break;
    case 5:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(2, 2);
        break;
    case 6:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(3, 2);
        break;
    case 7:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(1, 3);
        break;
    case 8:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(2, 3);
        break;
    case 9:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(3, 3);
        break;
    case 10:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(4, 2);
        break;
    case 11:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(5, 2);
        break;
    case 12:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(4, 3);
        break;
    case 13:
        this.image = Sprite.getSprite(5, 3);
        break;
    }
}
```

This is based off of notch's Ludum Dare Game "MiniCraft". However, I cant seem to figure out an efficient way to implement it with my methods.

If my math is correct (which it probably isn't) but wouldn't that mean there is 65,535 possible outcomes? (4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4)??

I love programming and all but not that much lol...

Can anyone help me figure out an algorithm or at least point me in the right direction please?

I know it's a really big question but all the help would be greatly appreciated!

Sav.

EDIT:
This is the way notch solves this issue.
He uses a grid sprite sheet similar to mine. However, to get the intended sprite he has an x & y co-ordinate which he multiplies by 32 (size of grid box).

```
    boolean u = !level.getTile(x, y - 1).connectsToGrass;
    boolean d = !level.getTile(x, y + 1).connectsToGrass;
    boolean l = !level.getTile(x - 1, y).connectsToGrass;
    boolean r = !level.getTile(x + 1, y).connectsToGrass;

    if (!u && !l) {
        screen.render(x * 16 + 0, y * 16 + 0, 0, col, 0);
    } else
        screen.render(x * 16 + 0, y * 16 + 0, (l ? 11 : 12) + (u ? 0 : 1) * 32, transitionColor, 0);

    if (!u && !r) {
        screen.render(x * 16 + 8, y * 16 + 0, 1, col, 0);
    } else
        screen.render(x * 16 + 8, y * 16 + 0, (r ? 13 : 12) + (u ? 0 : 1) * 32, transitionColor, 0);

    if (!d && !l) {
        screen.render(x * 16 + 0, y * 16 + 8, 2, col, 0);
    } else
        screen.render(x * 16 + 0, y * 16 + 8, (l ? 11 : 12) + (d ? 2 : 1) * 32, transitionColor, 0);
    if (!d && !r) {
        screen.render(x * 16 + 8, y * 16 + 8, 3, col, 0);
    } else
        screen.render(x * 16 + 8, y * 16 + 8, (r ? 13 : 12) + (d ? 2 : 1) * 32, transitionColor, 0);
}
```

As you can see he uses the (boolean ? true : false) method to receive the desired number to add for the sprite.

The issue i am having is figuring out a way i can use a similar algorithm to figure out which sprite I need to use.

This is what i am asking for. I would even be happy with seeing how anybody else has overcome this problem.

Thanks

Comment: So, you either have 4 or 8 adjacent positions, depending on whether you want to account for diagonal adjacency.  If you keep it simple, you can just look at left/right/up/down, each of which can be connected or not - so 4 positions in one of 2 states, or 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 16 possibilities.  Basically, you'd need to create a tile for each combination - 4 that connect in one direction only, 4*3/2 = 6 that connect in two directions, 4 that connect in all but one direction, one that connects in all directions, and one that connects in none.  If you do 8-way, then you have 2^8 = 256 tiles possible.

Comment: That is, for each square, you have 16 or 256 possible combinations - but each square should be independent from the others (i.e. your adjacency's adjacencies shouldn't affect you).

Comment: Yeh I thought my math was wrong lol... Originally i had 256 but thought wayy too deep lol..

Ok well... I have every Tile possible already drawn up. 
It's not the understanding of what i need to do, its the algorithm required to DO what i need to do lol... ok so maybe i'm not explaining this correctly. here is a code snippet from how notch deals with this problem. I will edit my original post showing this method.

BTW thank you for your reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give an answer for the 4-direction 16-case version (easier to visualize, and much shorter to write out) but the idea extends to the 8-directional case.   If I'm reading right, you want to figure out how to lay out your sprites so you can figure out based on u,l,d,r which position you need.

You basically have a 4 bit number here - where each bit corresponds to connectedness in one direction.  So you can generate your sprites:

```
ULDR 
0000: No connections
0001: Right side connected
0010: Down connected
0011: Down and right connected
0100: Left connected
0101: Left and right connected
0110: Left and down connected
0111: Left, right, and down connected
...
1111: Up, left, down and right all connected.
```

You could do a sprite strip (one dimension strip of sprites), in that order.  Sprite[0] = 0000, Sprite[1] = 0001, .... Sprite[15] = 1111.   Then to get your sprite, you'd just look for:

```
index = (up ? 0x8 : 0) | (left ? 0x4 : 0) | (down ? 0x2 : 0) | (right ? 0x1 : 0); 
s = sprite.getSprite(index, 0);
```

Now, if for some reason you WANT a 2D sprite (say if it's done as a texture that needs to be sized as 2^n x 2^n or something - I'm not a graphics guy, I dunno), you can do this like:

```
x_index = (up ? 0x2 : 0) | (left ? 0x1 : 0);
y_index = (right ? 0x2 : 0) | (down ? 0x1 :0); 
s = sprite.getSprite(x_index, y_index);
```

In either case, you just have to arrange the sprites to match the pattern.  I listed out the ordering above for the first one.  For a 2-dimensional sprite, you basically have a corresponding sprite layout:

```
   DR
UL      00   01   10   11 
   00 0000 0001 0010 0011
   01 0100 0101 0110 0111
   10 1000 1001 1010 1011 
   11 1100 1101 1110 1111
```

Again, where the bits correspond to connectedness to ULDR, respectively.  If you lay out the sprites as above, and use the algorithm above, it should work (unless I screwed up and flipped my Xs and Ys, which I sometimes do :)

Now, if you want to go with the 8 dimensional case, the idea is the same, except that you have 8 bits instead of 4:

UL U UR L R DL D DR

But it's just the matter of extending everything to 8 bit numbers:
         UUUL 
         L R
     RDDD     0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 ... 
      L R
         0000 
         0001 
         0010 
         .
         .
         .

Hope that makes sense (and hope I'm answering the right question).

Comment: You're a wizard! lol... Thank you so much, I totally understand this method and I'm about to implement it now.
Your answer is much appreciated!

Sav